# Flash running in Chromium and FF at once, why no sound in the second browser?

Tags: linux, audio, firefox, adobe-flash, chrome

I work as a student assistant Linux admin and I just packaged up Adobe's "Square" plugin to get 64bit FF running flash pretty well (first time I've seen it work this well), but there's one little problem I've come across thus far: if you open one browser and start using flash the second browser will not be able to output sound. I realize this is probably because of what sound driver is being used but is there any good way to fix this or is this just how it is for Flash being the bane of my existence?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described on the [FedoraProject wiki on Flash](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Flash), you might need the PulseAudio ALSA module.  If one of the browser's flash plugin (or pulseaudio itself) has locked the sound device, other apps trying to use the sound device might not succeed.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly - just installed alsa-plugins-pulseaudio.i686, I suspected some explanation like yours, but I wasn't sure how to actually fix it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you can play sound in *any* second application. Back when I used Linux on the desktop some audio drivers couldn't mix two audio streams. I really hope that would have been fixed by now, but you never know...

If you really can't play two simultaneous audio sources then you'll want to install an audio mixing daemon (e.g., esound or similar). A mixing daemon will intercept audio signals, mix them itself then send a single combined audio stream to the dsp.

But if you can play sound from a second audio source then I'm completely wrong.